# Filter query result for every Thursday of a given month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL table with 2 columns ID (int) and CreateDate (DateTime) type.
I want to filter all the IDs for each Thursday for a given month whether I pick Jan, Feb, March, etc...

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function might help you to do that.

you can use `weekday` in the first parameter which returns weekday from DateTime, if you want to compare others information `DATEPART` might help you compare.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE  
    DATEPART ( weekday , CreateDate ) = 5
```

Comment: Thursday by default should be 5 NOT 4. SQL Server starts Sunday = 1, Monday = 2... so Thursday = 5

Comment: @taji01 That would depend on your language setting. For [U.S. English](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) Thursday is 4 by default.

Answer (score 2):

> for each Thursday for a given month

Start by filtering on the month/year date range first, to reduce the number of results and keep things [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Then use [datePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify the Thursday's within the selected range.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5238e724d38571e6537269646841a797)

```
-- Assumes SET DATEFIRST 7 
SELECT * 
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  CreateDate >= '2022-01-01'
AND    CreateDate < '2022-02-01'
AND    DatePart(dw, CreateDate) = 5
```

Note, the results of Datepart(dw) [may differ depending on your @@DATEFIRST setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). A deterministic version of the query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  CreateDate >= '2022-01-01'
AND    CreateDate < '2022-02-01'
AND    ((DatePart(dw, CreateDate) + @@DATEFIRST-1) % 7+1) = 5
```